# Mafia II and Physx woes

Tags: amd-catalyst, physx

I'm trying to play Mafia II on my PC. I have previously played it on this computer but it no longer works. If anyone knows a solution to any of the below issues then it may solve them all.

Issues:

- Error on game startup - Physx SDK not initialized. Physx System software will be installed (doesn't install)
- Manual install of Physx results in error "Internal Error 2755. 1632"
- Installation of CCC 13.4 results in error "Temporary folder inaccessible" - [log](http://pastebin.com/1S4hVPA4)

As I understand it Physx should not actually need to be installed seeing as I have an ATI card. I've tried tutorials online to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error code means you have an issue with your temp folder:

```
C:\Users\André>err 1632
# for decimal 1632 / hex 0x660
  ERROR_INSTALL_TEMP_UNWRITABLE                                  winerror.h
# The Temp folder is on a drive that is full or is
# inaccessible. Free up space on the drive or verify that you
# have write permission on the Temp folder.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: SUCCESS (0), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x660
# for decimal 1632 / hex 0x660
  ERROR_INSTALL_TEMP_UNWRITABLE                                  winerror.h
# The Temp folder is on a drive that is full or is
# inaccessible. Free up space on the drive or verify that you
# have write permission on the Temp folder.
# 2 matches found for "1632"
```

Make sure you have writing permissions to `C:\Windows\Temp` and `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I checked that I have access to the folders and I do. I've updated the original post with a paste of the CCC install log now.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks so much. Your post led me to finding this useful article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811881. It mentioned Windows/Installer. I noted that I didn't have the folder. I created it and took ownership. Physx installed straight away.